# WordPress 4-letter comment error

Tags: wordpress

This is one of the weirdest bugs I've seen. I recently uploaded WordPress onto one of my new sites, http://viewmixed.com/, and there is a strange bug when posting four-letter words.

At first I thought you couldn't leave comments at all because I kept trying to leave a comment with the word "test". I then realized that any four letter word seems to break the comments i.e. "four" or "1234", but any other string posts the comment fine.

I have tried deleting all the files/database and then re-installing WP, and that didn't solve anything. I'm on the newest WP version, 3.5.1, and I also tried installing 3.4.2 and 3.1.4, but none fixed the issue...

Anyone have an idea of what could be going on?

EDIT: I forgot to mention that I do have a custom theme right now, but the bug was there before installing the theme, and I also tried changing themes, but the 4-letter bug doesn't go away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not easy to answer this in detail because there are a couple of reasons for getting this error, but as you can see in the title there is an error with `406 Not Acceptable` which is probably a `MOD_SECURITY` problem.

Frist change the permalink settings within WordPress and look if the error still appears.

Second try to deactivate `MOD_SECURITY`. 
Therefore you can add a `.htaccess` file within your `wp-admin` directory...

```
<IfModule mod_security.c>
SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>
```

...or add a `.htaccess` file within the `root` to disable it completely:

```
<IfModule mod_security.c>
SecFilterEngine Off
</IfModule>
```

If it still does not work I would suggest to contact your hosting provider to do this for you.

As it is not easy to find the solution for something like this (and for further reading) I suggest reading [this blogpost](http://activeblogging.com/info/406-error-wordpress/) which is on finding the 406 error and [this blogpost](http://techforworld.com/406-not-acceptable-error-wordpress-solution/) for another similar solution within WordPress.

Hopefully this might be helpful for you.